# Streaming concatenation

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In SystemVerilog IEEE Std 1800-2017 page 277, the following example is shown :

```
int a, b, c;
logic [10:0] up [3:0];
logic [11:1] p1, p2, p3, p4;
bit [96:1] y = {>>{ a, b, c }}; // OK: pack a, b, c
int j = {>>{ a, b, c }}; // error: j is 32 bits < 96 bits
bit [99:0] d = {>>{ a, b, c }}; // OK: d is padded with 4 bits
{>>{ a, b, c }} = 23'b1; // error: too few bits in stream
{>>{ a, b, c }} = 96'b1; // OK: unpack a = 0, b = 0, c = 1
{>>{ a, b, c }} = 100'b11111; // OK: unpack a = 0, b = 0, c = 1 // 96 MSBs unpacked, 4 LSBs truncated
{ >> {p1, p2, p3, p4}} = up; // OK: unpack p1 = up[3], p2 = up[2],
                             // p3 = up[1], p4 = up[0]
```

Regarding this line:

```
{>>{ a, b, c }} = 96'b1; // OK: unpack a = 0, b = 0, c = 1
```

Why do `a` and `b` get the value of 0?

Comment: Flat wires can be unpacked without the streaming operator: `{a, b, c} = 96'd1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the IEEE Std 180-2017, section 11.4.14.3 *Streaming concatenation as an assignment target (unpack)*

> When a streaming_concatenation appears as the target of an assignment,
>   the streaming operators perform the reverse operation; i.e., to unpack
>   a stream of bits into one or more variables.

a, b and c are declared as `int`, which means they are each 32 bits wide.  The constant `96'b1` is 96 bits wide (95 MSB's are 0, LSB is 1).  Since 96 = 3 x 32, `a` will be assigned the most significant 32 bits (32 0's), `b` will be assigned the middle 32 bits (32 0's), and `c` will be assigned the least significant 32 bits (31 0's, and a 1).

```
00000000000000000000000000000000_00000000000000000000000000000000_00000000000000000000000000000001

|<-----------  a  ------------>| |<-----------  b  ------------>| |<-----------  c  ------------>|
```